# Bootstrap Navbar Images not appearing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, image, navbar

I'm having trouble getting images that are files in my application to appear. Right now in it's place is just an icon indicating that their should be an image present. I am specifically working on the logo (navbar-brand) right now. For now the images are in the same folder.

What can I do to display and resize the graphic appropriately?

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width= width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <style>
    /* Remove the navbar's default margin-bottom and rounded borders */
    .navbar {
      margin-bottom: 0;
      border-radius: 0;
    }

    /* Add a gray background color and some padding to the footer */
    footer {
      background-color: #f2f2f2;
      padding: 25px;
    }

  .carousel-inner img {
      width: 100%; /* Set width to 100% */
      margin: auto;
      min-height:200px;
  }

  .navbar-brand {
  width: 57px;
  height: 27px;
  }
  .navbar-brand img {
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  }

  /* Hide the carousel text when the screen is less than 600 pixels wide */
  @media (max-width: 600px) {
    .carousel-caption {
      display: none;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>

      <div class="pull-left">
          <img src="rsz_1logo" class="navbar-brand">
      </div>

    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><%= link_to "Home", root_path %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'Learn More', controller: 'posts' %> </li>
        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li><%= link_to 'Calculate Water Footprint', controller: 'waterusages' %></li>
        <li><%= link_to 'See Your Usage', waterusage_result_path %></li>
        <% end %>

        <!--  <a href="/">Calculate Water Footprint</a></li> -->
        <!-- <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li> -->
        <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <% if !user_signed_in? %>
        <li> <%= link_to('Sign Up', new_user_registration_path)  %> </li>
        <li> <%= link_to('Login', new_user_session_path)  %> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> </li>
        <% end %>

        <% if user_signed_in? %>
        <li> <%= link_to('Logout', destroy_user_session_path, method: :delete) %> </li>
        <% end %>

      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `src="rsz_1logo"` is not appropriate source. Also in rails, you have to store the images in `app/assets/images` directory. 

And in your HTML, replace `<img>` with `<%= image_tag "your_image.jpg", alt="Alt text" %>`

Answer (score 0):

Two things.

First you should use the image_tag helper to generate the image elements in your Html, instead of hardcoding the src attribute.

Secondly you need to place your images into the assets directory.

The Rails guides should help.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#asset-organization

Comment: The image_tag and guide did help displaying the image but I still haven't seen how to resize it.

Comment: To resize it, give the class to your `<%= image_tag %>`. 
Here is how it is `<%= image_tag "your_image.jpg", alt="Alt text", class: "logo"  %>`.

Now you can use css `.logo { }`